# Using variable from constructor in member function

Tags: c++, function, file, constructor, member

I have the following class which has a constructor that reads in a txt file which contains the size of `object` which the constructor should make. Then I need the function `read()` to pick up where the constructor stopped, but for some reason it starts at the top of the file again. How is this fixed?

```
class Reader {
public:
    Reader(const char* file): _file(file) {
        _ptr = 0;
        ifstream _file(file);

        _file >> word;
        if(word!="BEGIN") {
            //Raise error.
        }

        _file >> word; //Reads in next word.
        if(word=="SIZE") {
            _file >> size_x;
            _file >> size_y;

            _ptr = new Object(size_x,size_y);
        }
        else {
           //Raise error.
        }

        _file >> word;

        while(word=="POSITION") {
            int readoutID;
            int ix;
            int iy;
            _file >> readoutID >> ix >> iy;

            //Set ID to position

            _file >> word;
        }

        std::cout << "End of definition: " << word << std::endl;
    }

    bool read(){
        std::cout << word << std::endl; // This word should be the one where the constructor stopped.
    //Returns False at the end if file.
    }

private: 
    Object* _ptr;
    std::ifstream _file;
    std::string word;
```

My main file looks like this:

```
int main(){

Reader r("file.dat");

while(r.read()) { 
//Function that prints out the values of read() 
} 

}
```

Comment: `_file` is stateful. You should continue where the constructor stopped to read automatically. Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: how do you call `read()`? and what has that to do with your constructor

Comment: I have a small main file that first creates an object of class `Reader` and then I call the `read()` function.  See edit.

Comment: Is word a member variable? Did you notice that in read you don't read from the file into the word but output the word?

Comment: That is just to simplify. If I do `_file >> word `, it reads in the first word of the file and not the next one where the constructor stopped.

Answer (score 0):

From your question *I need the function read() to pick up where the constructor stopped, but for some reason it starts at the top of the file again*: you not using `this->_file` but you create a local variable `_file`. Thus, the state of `this->_file` is the same as when it was opened: beginning of file.

Also, the constructor is not named correctly (`CaloReader` instead of `Reader`).

```
CaloReader(const char* file): _file(file) {
  _ptr = 0;
  ifstream _file(file);  // local variable
  _file >> word;
```

Comment: How would I exactly use `this->_file` ?

Comment: Are you learning C++ ? `this->_file` simply indicate you are using the _file attributes. You may also simply remove the variable declaration (as shown in my answer). However, seeing your need, you need to move away the code that reads words outside the constructor : it must go in the read method.